# How to get a solution without any hard score by optaplanner engine

Tags: java, optaplanner

We want to find a way how to avoid hard scores for the optaplanner solutions.

In our enterprise optimization project, it's not allowed to generate a solution with hard constraint scores. But actually the generated results by Optaplanner engine always have some allocations with hard constraint scores. when this situation happens, we will try to move the entity to the null allocation currently instead to clean the hard scores.

The above solution seems not the right way to avoid hard scores. Are there other methods to achieve that goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the user guide, see **overconstrained planning**. An approach of `nullable=true` and a medium score penalty on every null assignment should do what you want. See K88's answer too.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to know what is the issue without having any example of the algorithm configuration and examples of the problem, but hope this helps.

If you get constraint violations (as that is what hard scores are) in your solution it means no feasible solution is being found. This can have a couple of reasons:
* There is no feasible solution to begin with
* The optimisation algorithm doesn't step fast enough or the termination makes it terminate too early.

Depending on the problem at hand it can be hard to verify whether a feasible solution exists, but one could draft a simple problem that is to be solved by Optaplanner to verify whether it can find it (it should be able to). If it doesn't then something is wrong with the modelling or objective function.

For the second point the best way to go forward is to keep track of the score calculation speed, it should preferably be in the thousands of steps per second ( > 1000/sec). If it isn't investigate using `Drools` or `IncrementalScoreCalculator` for fasting computation. Also, use the benchmarker module to see if your algorithm is appropriately configured.

Lastly, do you have a local search phase ? A construction phase alone is way more likely to return an infeasible solution as opposed to one with a local search phase.